# Determine if NSUInteger has a value or is nil

Tags: ios, healthkit, nsuinteger

I'm trying to use a `HKAnchoredObjectQuery` on iOS.

To do so I have to provide an anchor to the query which in this case is a `NSUInteger`. I want to save this integer for queries in the future in the `NSUserDefaults` and just simply want to use

`if(anchor != nil) {
// do stuff
}`

But the complier tells me that I'm not allowed to do this because I'm comparing a integer to a pointer and I understand why I'm not able to do this but I don't know how to do it.

The error code is this

`Comparison between pointer and integer ('NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'void *')`

Does anyone know how I'm able to determine if my anchor has a value or not?

Comment: Use this as anchor is NSUInteger , so if(anchor != 0) { //do stuff }

Comment: Use a NSNumber to  hold the integer which you can compare against nil. If the object is not in UserDefaults then it is not set. Otherwise it has the value inside the NSNumber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSUInteger is a primitive type, not an object type. NSNumber is an object type. For an NSNumber object, you can check whether it is nil or not. An NSUInteger is never nil because it is an integer, not a pointer.

Many functions that return NSUInteger as a result for a search return the constant NSNotFound if the search failed. NSNotFound is defined as a very large integer (2^31 - 1 for 32 bit, 2^63 - 1) for 64 bit).

Comment: Pro tip: `NSNotFound` is a negation so you have to make your statement true otherwise it will just skip over your `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

`NSUInteger` is not an object and cannot be compared to nil. In over-simplistic terms, an object is a pointer to a memory location that may contain an value or be `nil`. `NSUInteger` is just a value. It may be `0`, or some other value that you don't expect, but it will have a value.

Answer (score 0):

An `NSUInteger` cannot be nil because it is not an object. The default value on creation would be zero. To save in `NSUserDefaults`, you could store it as an `NSNumber`, which could be checked for nil later.

To store it in `NSUserDefaults`:

```
NSNumber *aNumber = @(anchor);
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:aNumber forKey:aKey];
```

To get the anchor back from `NSUserDefaults`:

```
NSNumber *aNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:aKey];
if (aNumber != nil) {
    NSUInteger anchor = [aNumber integerValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSUInteger` or simply int are basically primitive data types and they should be compared with the integer values with in the range of the corresponding data types. nil is used with referenced objects.

In your case, as anchor is `NSUInteger` so you should use integer value for comparison in place of nil as-

```
if(anchor != 0) {
// do stuff
}
```